# Java 8 - Functional Interface vs Abstract class

Tags: java, functional-interface

I was exploring features of Java 8 and came across **"Functional Interface"**.

As per my understanding, these interfaces can have some default implemented methods as :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ComplexFunctionalInterface extends SimpleFuncInterface 
{
    default public void doSomeWork()
    {
        System.out.println("Doing some work in interface impl...");
    }
    default public void doSomeOtherWork()
    {
        System.out.println("Doing some other work in interface impl...");
    }
}
```

But my doubt is, this what abstract class is for.

Why introduce **functional interfaces**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> But my doubt is, this what abstract class is for.
>
> Why introduce functional interfaces.

Number of classes that can be extended: `1`

Number of interfaces that can be implemented: `more than 1`

Comment: Is this the only reason? Java was very provide till jdk1.7 for not having multiple inheritance.

Comment: You still don't have multiple inheritance. You only inherit from one source, but you can implement multiple interfaces - same as before. The inheritance graph is still a directed acyclic graph.

Comment: But, by implementing multiple functional interface, won't diamond problem?

Comment: @Batty apparently the diamond problem only kicks in if default function implementations are provided in the functional interface (also a new thing) - compiler solves this by forcing implementing classes to provide implementation of these methods when multiple default implementations are found in the interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

Functional interface are is used in a "safe" multiple inheritance. Differences:

- A class may extend *multiple functional interfaces*.
- Functional interfaces may have only a *single abstract method*.
- Functional interfaces *may not have fields* unlike C++ abstract classes.

**Typical usage** is when you want to embed default functionality into objects. I.e. if you have a function-like object,

```
class MyFunction1 {
    public Integer apply(String s){
        ...
    }
}

class MyFunction2 {
    public List<String> apply(Integer s){
        ...
    }
}
```

And you want to make a composition out of them, you just drop in `implements Function`:

```
class MyFunction1 implements Function<String, Integer>{
    public Integer apply(String s){
        ...
    }
}

class MyFunction2 implements Function<Integer, List<String>>{
    public List<String> apply(Integer s){
        ...
    }
}
```

And you may create a composition of your functions. Two approaches compared:

**No functional interfaces:**

```
MyFunction1 myFunction1 = ...;
MyFunction2 myFunction2 = ...;

Function<String, List<String>> composition = (s) -> myFunction2.apply(myFunction1.apply(s));
```

**With functional  interfaces:**

```
MyFunction1 myFunction1 = ...;
MyFunction2 myFunction2 = ...;

Function<String, List<String>> composition = myFunction1.andThen(myFunction2);
```

**The difference**

- **No need to re-implement** functions.
- **Other functions available** in the extending class: `compose` and `identity`.
- New default function is made a **part of a class hierarchy** and there is **no need to create a new object**. Usually functions like `compose()` are not included into a class definition as it would result into class size growth. They are often put into separate utility classes. In Guava composition is put into a separate utility class `Functions`: [Functions.compose](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Functions.html#compose%28com.google.common.base.Function,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29). So with new functional interfaces you would not need to recall in which utility class your function is implemented.

Comment: what if both interface have method as "public Integer apply(String s)", won't this be a problem?

Comment: If functional interfaces have the same signature for their abstract methods, this would result into compile-time error. I understand this as method inlining - one can't have duplicate methods in his classes.

Answer (score 1):

Functional interfaces must have only one method. The only exception is mehtods declared in Object. See http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-functional-1

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with JAVA 8 yet, but from what I can see this would allow for a kind of multiple inheritance, which is not possible with abstract classes

Comment: It's still not multiple inheritance.

Comment: @MarkusKoivisto: Why not? You can have variables and methods with a body. Is there something lacking that you say, this is not multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

The interface Comparator is functional although it explicitly declares two methods, because only one is abstract; equals is an explicit declaration of a concrete method inherited from Object that, without this declaration, would otherwise be implicitly declared.